# Graph of $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have found out that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

I want to know the behaviour of the graph as $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$. Any help and hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: *Hint:* $|\sin x\ | \leq 1$ for all $x$

Comment: Will it ever touch the axis ? I would actually like to see the workings of possible . Thanks .

Comment: Certainly it crosses the $x$ axis at $x = k\pi$ for all integers $k \neq 0$, as $\sin(k\pi) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: you have $$|\sin(x)|\leq 1$$ which gives $$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\leq \frac{1}{|x|}.$$ Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

As Simon has said, we can use the fact that $|sinx|\leq1 \quad\forall x$. Therefore, $$\left|\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{x}\right| = \frac{1}{|x|}$$

As $x \rightarrow \infty$, we have that

$$\left|\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right| \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x} = 0 \text{, by convention}$$

This is similar for $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

Since $\left|\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right| \geq 0$ always, i.e. the modulus is always greater than 0, we have that $$0 \leq \left|\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right| \leq 0 \text{ as } x\rightarrow \infty , x\rightarrow -\infty$$

Therefore, by the sandwich theorem, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right|=\lim_{x->-\infty}\left|\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right|=0$$

Comment: I'd be careful with writing $\frac{1}{\infty}$. One does understand what you mean, but the notation is at least questionable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I have changed it to hopefully make the notation more solid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plot obtained with LaTeX:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here you can find the searched plot of the function $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29%2Fx